# MS Access Query Goes Blank If No Rows In Another Query

Tags: ms-access

This has been driving me nuts for awhile now.

So I have Query_A and Query_B that I need to combine into one query called Query_C.
This works perfectly fine.  But if Query_B returns no results or zero rows because of a filter, then Query_C goes blank or to zero rows as well.

Is there any way to have Query_C still display the results of Query_A even if Query_B has no rows?

I have been doing null to zero in the past which works fine but its a pain to do it for each column and alot of times I have to make another query just for doing the null to zero part.  And on top of it then I have formatting problems and have to format each column as well.  It always ends up being so many queries and so much extra work it just seems dumb.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Need to show query SQL statements. Perhaps you need LEFT or RIGHT JOIN. Sample data as text tables can be useful.

Comment: Yup adding a left join solved the problem. Just made a dummy feild in each table and joined that.  Maybe I dont need the dummy feild though.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a subquery UNION or UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM
(Query_A UNION Query_B) AS Query_C

Comment: Without seeing your code it is difficukt to help you. You can change the name of your fields if its sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a left join solved the problem.  Made a dummy feild in each table and joined them with that for the test.